# Python Selenium to select a checkbox on dynamic web page

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, checkbox, web-scraping

I have tried several code snippets I found non did the job for me. Also, I inspect and found that the element am trying to select has ID so

> find_element_by_id

didn't work. I ahd also tried

> find_element_by_xpath **and** find_elements_by_name

Non of them worked. I want to be able to select a checkbox on [this website](http://www.osborneandlittle.com/products-and-collections/fabric)

My code looks like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = "the web page above"

# Creates an instance driver object for chrome browser...
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Get the url
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

# Find list elements by id and click/select on it....
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), 'Osborne & Little')]").click()
```

Comment: I tried your code. The xpath would be better like this: `"//*[text()[contains(.,'Osborne & Little')]]"` But then it would be a list, since the title contains the text, too, if it returned each elements. This is not the case, those radioboxes are not reachable somehow. A simple `"//input[@type='radio']"` gives back only 5 elements, so you have to find an other way to reach them...

Comment: I tried your xpath, I still get this error:        ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.99)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7600 x86_64)

Comment: Which one? That's a better result, I only got back the title. I don't think the waiting suggestions will help, because I also tried with waiting, and those radioboxes were not returned after tens of seconds later, but maybe you should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You are using xpath wrong.
Go to chrome->inspect-> cmd+F
you can try put in Xpath to test selecting element

Give you an example here

```
      <span class="tss-label tss-label--hierarchy ng-binding" ng-class="displayRow[instance.item.id] ? 'tss-hierarchy__selectedStateText' : ''" ng-bind="instance.item.alias" title="Node-1: Instance #1 - d07f2ec4-71f1-4ae0-81c6-955c86e14c6e">Node-1: Instance #1</span>
```

can be selected by

```
      xpath "//*[contains(@title,'Node-1: Instance #1')]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40889413/navigating-through-pagination-with-selenium-adding-items-to-a-hashmap/40916283#40916283) you need to find all the elements that you need to click on it and iterate them until finish, that example is with java but is the same principle

For your particular problem you can do the next or you can simplify with xpath but this is an example that would work for your specific problem

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.osborneandlittle.com/products-and-collections/fabric");
if (driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText("Osborne & Little")).isEmpty()) {
    new WebDriverWait(
            driver, TIME_TO_WAIT).until(
                    ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(
                            By.name("brand")));
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("label"));

    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
      String textInCurrentlabel = elements.get(i).getText();
      if (textInCurrentlabel.equals("Osborne & Little")) {
        elements.get(i).click();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you kindly type explain better with a code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the x-path from you specify is wrong but assuming that it's correct and that yours it's a load problem because you try to search the element before it's loaded, try this and let me know pls, in any case if you give me more details like the URL and the element that you need I'll able to help you more:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

url = "the web page above"

# Creates an instance driver object for chrome browser...
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Get the url
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

# Find list elements by id and click/select on it....
#wait the item is loaded
i=0
while i<1:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[contains(text(), 'Osborne & Little')]").click()
        i=1
    except:
        time.sleep(1)
        i=0
```

for be sure that you are using a correct x-path open the URL with firefox and install the plug-in firebug and firepath